# How can I create json output from deep li structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have ol li structure as html and I want to create JSON from that but my code doesn't create that JSON I need. Can any one please help me to solve it?

I need to create JSON like that

```
[
        {"en":"Menu1","enlink":"#enlink1","tr":"Menü 1","trlink":"#trlink1","data":[
            {"en":"Menu1-1","enlink":"#enlink1-1","tr":"Menü 1-1","trlink":"#trlink1-1","data":[
                {"en":"Menu1-1-1","enlink":"#enlink1-1-1","tr":"Menü 1-1-1","trlink":"#trlink1-1-1"},
                {"en":"Menu1-1-2","enlink":"#enlink1-1-2","tr":"Menü 1-1-2","trlink":"#trlink1-1-2"}
            ]},
        ]},
        {"en":"Menu2","enlink":"#enlink2","tr":"Menü 2","trlink":"#trlink2","data":[
            {"en":"Menu2-1","enlink":"#enlink2-1","tr":"Menü 2-1","trlink":"#trlink2-1"},
            {"en":"Menu2-1","enlink":"#enlink2-1","tr":"Menü 2-1","trlink":"#trlink2-1"}
        ]},
        {"en":"Menu3","enlink":"#enlink3","tr":"Menü 3","trlink":"#trlink3"}
        ]
```

And my sample codes are..

```js
var buildJson = function (root){
 if(!root){
  root='#domenu-en';
 }
 var result = [];
 $(' ol > li ',root).each(function() {
  if($(this).children("ol").length){
   result.push({"en":$(this).attr("data-en"),"data":buildJson($(this))});
   //return false;
  } else{
   result.push({"en":$(this).attr("data-en")});
  }
 });
 return result;
}
$('#results').val(JSON.stringify(buildJson()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="domenu-en">
<ol>
 <li data-enlink="#enlink1" data-en="Menu1" data-trlink="#trlink1" data-tr="Menü 1">
  <ol>
   <li data-enlink="#enlink1-1" data-en="Menu1-1" data-trlink="#trlink1-1" data-tr="Menü 1-1">
    <ol>
     <li data-enlink="#enlink1-1-1" data-en="Menu1-1-1" data-trlink="#trlink1-1-1" data-tr="Menü 1-1-1">
     </li>
     <li data-enlink="#enlink1-1-2" data-en="Menu1-1-2" data-trlink="#trlink1-1-2" data-tr="Menü 1-1-2">
     </li>
    </ol>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li data-enlink="#enlink2" data-en="Menu2" data-trlink="#trlink2" data-tr="Menü 2">
  <ol>
   <li data-enlink="#enlink2-1" data-en="Menu2-1" data-trlink="#trlink2-1" data-tr="Menü 2-1">
   </li>
   <li data-enlink="#enlink2-1" data-en="Menu2-1" data-trlink="#trlink2-1" data-tr="Menü 2-1">
   </li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li data-enlink="#enlink3" data-en="Menu3" data-trlink="#trlink3" data-tr="Menü 3">
 </li>
</ol>
</div>
<textarea id="results" style=" height: 279px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution its very simple, in case any one needed I like to share it. If we tell the jQuery select first li as **ol:first >li** then its generate same hierarchy as li structure.

```
var buildJson = function (root){
if(!root){
    root='#domenu-en';
}
var result = [];
$('ol:first > li ',root).each(function() {
var itemdata = {};
$.each($(this).data(), function(key, value) {
  itemdata[key] = value;
});

    if($(this).children("ol").length){

  itemdata["data"] = buildJson($(this));
    }

result.push(itemdata);
});
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference seem to be that you don't include the other `data-` attributes other than the `data-en`. You can iterate all of the `data-` attributes on an element with `$.each($(this).data(), function(key, value) {})`.

In your case that would be something like:

```
$(' ol > li ',root).each(function() {
    var itemdata = {};
    $.each($(this).data(), function(key, value) {
        itemdata[key] = value;
    });

    if($(this).children("ol").length){
        itemdata["data"] = buildJson($(this));
    }

    result.push(itemdata);
});
```

That should give you an equal JSON result. The properties may be in a different order, but that shouldn't matter for JSON (for example: your JSON example had the order en, enlink, tr and trlink, while I got tr, trlink, en and enlink in my example. The order of the menu items in the list is still the same (1, 1-1, 1-2, etc.).

A working example at https://jsfiddle.net/gpctm9d1/

Comment: Thanks for your efford @Thomas van den Berg but each time when we call function again it generates additional object. At the resul I have larger json out there shoıuld be one ** Menu1-1-1** but in this code and mine generates 4 same item in diffirent child. `$(' ol > li ',root).each(function() ` reachs sub li as well. Some how durring the proccess we have to interrupt to reach sub li.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured out the problem